# Dll redirection not working in C# to deal with dll-hell with dot local file (appname.exe.local)

Tags: c#, redirect, local, dll

I used to successfully test multiple versions of code without having to worry about dll dependency by creating a zero byte application_name.exe.local file in the folder containing the new version of the application. However, we have to move to C# and this technique is no longer working. Is there something else needed (other than .local file) to ensure C# dlls look at the current folder first and then go chase other dlls in the application’s default location?

Comment: You might want to attach to the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event and tell it how to load assemblies.

Comment: It is COM that is forced to look only in the same directory.  Same kind of COM you used before.  Must be some other problem, hard to guess what.  The COM server still needs to be registered.  If you are actually using C# to re-implement the COM server then, no, this can no longer work.  The assembly isn't loaded by COM, it is loaded by c:\windows\system32\mscoree.dll.  Google "reg-free COM manifest"

Answer (score 0):

You can always hook into the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event as Tejs suggests:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

...

public static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly AlreadyLoaded=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
    if(AlreadyLoaded==null)
        return Assembly.LoadFile(Path to corresponding DLL);
}
```

It's not perfect (may need to load the DLLs in whatever directory you want to search in and then replace the Assembly.LoadFile line with a search of those DLLs), but you should be able to modify that to work. Hopefully anyway.